# Modify an HTML tag level CSS selector from the code behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web

I want to be able to fully manipulate all CSS selectors (including classes and semantic tags) using the ASP.NET backend code. Like so:

**CSS**:

```
html {
    color: black;
}

.myClass {
    width: 100px;
}
```

***Desired* C#**:

```
protected void Page_Load(...) {
    // Some code & if logic ...
    html.Attributes.Add("style", "color: green")
    myClass.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 325px")
}
```

However, the C# aspect of it I do not know what to do to access semantic level tags. I am curious how to modify just the style classes from C# (i.e. do not mess with the ASP.NET / id's). This is for design aspects as CSS does not have certain logic behind it and I cannot make another "html" selector in CSS or C#.

**EDIT**:

Class applied to a generic div element containing other elements. runat="server"

Comment: on which control you assigning the css class??

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper good question. It is a standard div element that holds other items. It is just an example. It has the propery of runat set to "server". I just want to know how to modify the class directly via C# without using id's or creating a cloned version of the class with the 1 or 2 attributes changed, if that makes sense.

Comment: You don't appear to need to generate the style attributes since you are showing them as hard-coded. So, you can create a fixed CSS class that applies them. Then your problem simplifies to adding and removing classes to elements. In case you didn't know, the class attribute is a space-separated list.

Comment: @TomBlodget my goal is to modify those hard-coded styles on the fly in real time. For example, if a user clicks a button then the background color of the page should change, but I cannot make another html selector in CSS nor tell ASP.NET use the other "html" selector. Otherwise the color should remain as hard coded. I want to modify more than 1 attribute per style, but I did not want to over complicate my question. C# _should_ as far as I know, be able to have full and complete control over all aspects of the webpage.

Comment: This has a code and design smell. Maybe you can explain the business scenario - why would we ever be in a situation that necessitated changing all the HTML selectors on a page?

Comment: Lol, code and design smell. I do not want to change all of the HTML selectors on a page, but rather, quite literally the html selector itself in CSS. It is a single tag level selector for the element HTML (<html> ... all other stuff </html>) - Just that single tag is being targeted by the CSS style. The reason for modifying that selector over others is just because that is where the content was created on...and I do not have the time to remake/reverse engineer several pages, using hundreds of elements, having innumerable amounts of styles applied to them. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, I get what you're trying to do. But to be honest, I would just take the logical approach even if it is a bit tedious now. The other approach would be a nightmare to maintain for future devs not familiar with it. Maybe there's a dynamic way of achieving what you need using jQuery...

Comment: @IrishChieftain and to be clear, what is the "logical" approach? If I could put two html style selectors in CSS I would, but it just cannot be done AFAIK. I don't want to wrap everything in a div for fear of f'ing up some part of the design or having yet another issue with a class being applied to that new div and trying to override it. I thought the C# gave full and complete control over all the parts of the webpage, why are html selectors not part of the "package" if you will? jQuery is not a bad idea, but I have not tinkered with JS or client-side web development...so I can't really say.

Comment: Some of your HTML may be created on the fly? If so, that just complicates it further and the resulting code would be horrible. By "logical approach", I mean create the extra pages, whatever you have to do, to avoid what you're currently planning on doing ;-)

Comment: @IrishChieftain lol, and this is not directed at you, but I cannot believe it is so hard to change an attribute of a CSS HTML Tag Selector via C#. lol, seriously cannot believe the creators of the language(s)/markup(s) did not forsee that. lol - Thanks for the answer. I am not generating HTML on the fly...good god (just no...lol). I am just trying to change the CSS of html { ... } on the fly without taking already fubar'ed CSS and just nuking it to death. what if someone wanted to modify the <p> selector in CSS or the <article> selector via C#?

Comment: Absolutely possible to do that with C#. It's also possible to build a life-size replica of London Bridge with match sticks. That doesn't mean it's the best road to go ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS) CSS parser. I think you will be able to accomplish your task. If not, it is open source, you can use it as a guide.

This code below will find "url('/images/logo.png')"

```
var parser = new Parser();
var stylesheet = parser.Parse(".someClass{color: red; background-image: url('/images/logo.png')");

var imageUrl = stylesheet.Rulesets
            .SelectMany(r => r.Declarations)
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.Equals("background-image", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Term
            .ToString();
```

Comment: Hmm...not bad. Could be interesting to look into, but I am not sure if it is just overkill on steroids by implementing a parser into my project. Would client-side programming be easier? Why would something so obvious not be available via server-side? Dynamic design seems rather obvious and intuitive for developers, not sure why it is not supported in the back-end part of ASP.NET

Comment: most of the things are supported in the back-end. let us know what you want I am sure you will get the help. Make sure everything is not available using one tech like asp.net. you have to use jquery, js, css etc etc to achieve the task. but for that first I need to understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

whatever controls you want to access in the code, should be runat="server" and with id.

```
< div id="dv" runat="server">...your design in between...< /div>
```

from the backend , you can access it like this:

```
dv.Attributes.Add("style", "color: green");
```

well, I suggest to have a css, and you can assign the class directly:

```
dv.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
```

or

```
dv.cssClass ="myClass";
```

Note: if you are looking for different themes can be applied on the user selection refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366514.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8dd3df/themes-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: What if I need to modify the "html" selector? How do I access that from C#? ID's are strongly discouraged among design I thought? I don't use that many id's and most of my design is done via CSS class selectors.

Comment: if you want to set it via code than it would be tough. because your page must have hundreds of DIV tags. how you can find the one you need?

Comment: Ideally I am setting a CSS class selector so that way I can make sweeping design changes in only a few simple lines versues going through hundreds of div tags via id's. The classes are just what the site was developed around and it makes design changes far less cumbersome in CSS and should be the same via C# if I can modify them on the fly via C# depending on certain criteria.

Comment: why not. Yes you can. if you provide the details what you want to achieve it will be very easy to understand your question

Comment: I am not sure how to rephrase it any more simply. I have a CSS HTML Tag Selector of html { color: black, font-family: Arial; ... } right. WITHOUT hard coding into the CSS file how do I modify _that_ html tag selector's attributes on the fly via C#? So, change color: black to color: green for example...all via C# on the server. Does that make sense?

Comment: or even via JS/jQuery. i.e. via programmatic means where other control values can be checked against if logic.

Comment: got your point. its highly impossible using any tech like jquery, js or .net. why you want to do like that.. even in that case also you have to do static coding. this is not how CSS framework designed to work with. put your business logic and people will help you to get it done in more proper way.